# Get sport activity from Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is anybody know if I can get sports activity like (walking, cycling) from Facebook Graph API?

Now I use this link

```
me/feed/?fields=application
```

and I receiving something like this:

```
{
  "application": {
    "category": "Lifestyle",
    "link": "http://www.endomondo.com/",
    "name": "Endomondo Sports Tracker",
    "namespace": "endoapp",
    "id": "20242565452"
  },
```

Can I filter the feed to show only sport activity? (not only from endomondo, but any others app like strava, garmin etc.)

Comment: i don´t think you can filter them, you will most likely have to filter them on your own.

Comment: so I must know every application namespace? Can I found this somewhere?